# Dual Boot Problems: Can't Boot Windows after using easyBCD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

quite new at this, so any help would be appreciate. I've spent a load of time researching and haven't found a good answer so I'm asking here.

Basic Problem: I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion 14 Sleekbook to dual boot along side windows. I had tried this a year earlier (actually it was 12.04) and got it working (I think I used easyBCD but honestly can't remember) but at some point Ubuntu stopped booting and I was too busy to mess with it. I followed instructions for getting rid of ubuntu and it seemed to work but whenever I turned on my machine the windows boot loader would offer me Ubuntu or Windows. I ignored it and went about my business.

So the other day with some time on my hands, I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB. Everything seem to go fine, but when I couldn't boot into Ubuntu. Thinking I could fix any issues associated with the last go around I used the reset function on EasyBCD and afterwards created (I thought!) a new slot for Windows, figuring I would make sure that works before moving onto Ubuntu. Well, it didn't. When I reset the computer it immediately goes to a blank screen with an occasional flicker in the beginning. Windows won't boot. Eventually I figured out that if I press f10 in the very start it gives me the option of loading Windows 8 or configuration. If I hit windows 8 it goes back to the blank screen. If I hit esc it gives me a list of boot options which include Ubuntu and my USB, but not Windows. I can also access the BIOS and boot options.

Ubuntu seems to boot fine and I am happily using it, but I would really like to get my Windows boot back and the files stuck on that partition. I ran boot-repair in Ubuntu and there are no changes to behavior. Here is the URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/8284130 from boot-repair.

I should also note that Windows came pre-installed and there was no System Restore disc (there is also no DVD drive). Is it possible, if necessary, to create one on a USB?

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

New computers come with UEFI Windows installations.

EasyBCD is not UEFI capable.

You need a Recovery CD/DVD/USB for your version of Windows, I suppose Windows 8.1 64-bit.

If you have a Microsoft key for your Windows 8/8.1 you can always download a Windows 8/8.1 ISO from Microsoft, burn it to DVD/USB and repair Windows. Google will help you to find articles how to do this.